# Set offsetfor Block in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

How can I set Margin property for some Block in RichTextBox element in Windows Phone?

```
<RichTextBox>
    <Paragraph>Today I am going to talk about RichTextBox, I know you must be having lot of expectations from this RichTextBox. Here I will try my best to make you aware of what will work and what will not work in this short post for RichTextBox in Windows Phone </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `InlineUIContainer` and put TextBlock in it:

```
<RichTextBox>
            <Paragraph>
                <InlineUIContainer>
                    <TextBlock Text="Today I am going to talk about RichTextBox, I know you must be having lot of expectations from this RichTextBox. Here I will try my best to make you aware of what will work and what will not work in this short post for RichTextBox in Windows Phone"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Margin="10" />
                </InlineUIContainer>
            </Paragraph>
        </RichTextBox>
```